# Global-font-size affects grid

Tags: sass, zurb-foundation-6

In Foundation 6 docs:

> Since the typical default browser font size is 16 pixels, that makes the calculation for grid size. If you want your base font size to be different and not have it affect the grid breakpoints, set `$rem-base` to `$global-font-size` and make sure `$global-font-size` is a pixel value.

I do as it is written and my grid with 12 columns has 1050 instead of 1200px. Is this a problem with `rem-calc()`? This can be somehow fixed or bypassed?

It is not a duplicate, no response from similar topics aren't helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Strange: function `rem-calc()` is in `_unit.scss` file and takes default `$rem-base` value, but not that defined by me. Just in `_settings.scss` move `$global-font-size` and `$rem-base` before `@import 'util/util';`.

Stupid bug wasted few days :P